# How to I add unique id's to mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big mysql database. There are 800000 records. But there is no uids they have. How can i add uids automaticly?

Comment: Create a new GUID column for the table and populate it with UUID() values

Comment: It is not quite clear -- maybe explaining the downvotes. What are your looking for: how to add an auto-generated id column to your table? an unique index? Or an [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) column?

Comment: It is language problem. English is not my native language so it is difficult to explain query problems mostly @sylvain-leroux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE  `your_table_name` 
    ADD  `uid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

Be patient after executing this statement.

EDIT:

```
 ALTER TABLE `your_table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT = 300000;
```

Comment: 13 seconds. thank you @mihai and simple problem. how to it starts with 300000 + ? because there are different tables they have unique ids they use 0 - 300000 numbers

Comment: @htaccess Sorry,I don`t understand.You want the field to start from 30000 onward?

Comment: yes. first query should start from 300000  @mihai edit: thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
    ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
    ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');
```

[Refer This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)